# Laravel - Wont upload image to database

Tags: database, image, laravel, validation

It returns FAILED, i have no idea why, it does not upload the img

```
public function updatelogo(Request $request)
{
  if($request->hasFile('logo')){
        $logo = $request->file('logo');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($logo)->resize(50, 50)->save( public_path('/images/games/' . $filename ) );

        $game_id = $request->input('game');

        $games = Games::where('id', '=', $game_id)->get();
        $games->logourl = $filename;
        $games->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with("status", "Succesfully edited!");
      }
      return redirect()->back()->with("status", "FAILED!");
}
```

FRONTEND:

```
<form action="{{ url('/admin/sitesettings/games/edit/logo') }}" method="POST">
                           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label for="logo" class="col-md-4 control-label">Logo</label>
                               <small>Upload a logo</small>
                               <select name="game" id="game">
                                 @foreach($games as $game)
                                  <option value="{{$game->id}}">{{$game->name}}</option>
                                 @endforeach
                                </select>
                               <div>
                                   <input id="logo" type="file" class="form-control" name="logo">
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                     </form>
```

Could you help me out now? i have no clue why it will not work tho

Answer (score 0):

it seems something wrong on your request, you didn't upload the image with using `logo`, please paste your frontend code, so I can help you.

Comment: I added it on the top @wanghanlin